# Subtraction using while loop Java

Tags: java, while-loop

So i'm trying to write a programme whereby the user enters two integers .
The programm is supposed to subtract 5 from the second integer entered in a loop depending on the first number entered. (so the first number should dictate how many times it will loop.

```
public int getScheme1() {
    while (Mark >= 20) {
        System.out.printf((Mark = Mark - 5) + Mark + "  ");
    }

    for (int Day = 1; Day <= 20; Day++) {
        System.out.printf("( " + Day + "):" + Mark + "  ");
    }

    return Mark;
}
```

All my code does is print the user's second input integer 20 times.
Also im sorry  im totally new to java

Comment: Are you saying that the first number entered defines how many times you're going to subtract 5 from the second number? For example `First number: 3` `Second number:  25` would give you output of `10`.

Comment: Assume the input numbers are n1 and n2, if n2 need to minus 5 in n1 times, why not just `n2 -= n1*5` instead of looping?

Answer (score 1):

you must call this function in your main program.

```
public int getScheme1 (int num1, int num2){
    for(int i = 1 ; i >= num1 ; i++ ){
        num2 -= 5;
    }
    return num2;
}
```

to call it simply use `getScheme1(num1,num2);`

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you described, you are looking for something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //create a scanner to get user input
int a1 = input.nextInt(); //get 2 ints from the user
int a2 = input.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < a1; i++) { //loop as many times as a1 specifies
    a2-=5; //subtract 5 from a2 each time it loops
}
System.out.println(a2);
```

The key part of this is the for loop, which works in the following:

`for(variable; condition; increment)`,
basically, what the for loop I wrote is saying:

Set `i = 0` at the start. If `i` is meeting the condition (in this case being less then `a1`), then loop. The increment part is called when it finishes running the code block, it now makes `i` bigger (in this case `1` bigger using `++`) Another important thing to note is that the first time the loop runs, i = 0.

So for example, if I wanted to loop 10 times, with a starting variable of 3 and incremented 5 each time, I'd do:

`for(int i = 3; i <= 53; i+=5) {}`

Also, one last thing: please look at [variable naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), variables shouldn't start with caps like that, they should be `camelCase`